# Reformat/Rewirte Execution Response - Calling an apps script as an executable API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Is there a way to change the body response when using the method: scripts.run (https://developers.google.cn/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run?hl=zh-cn)

As in the documentation (https://developers.google.cn/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run?hl=zh-cn#request-body) stated this is the response I receive.

```
{
  "done": true,
  "response": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse",
    "result": {
      "version": "v2",
      "content": {
        "messages": [
          {
            "text": "simple text with button",
            "type": "text"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I would like to change it. Why? The software I use requires a special kind of response format to process the data.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Basically, I want this part to disappear:

```
"done": true,
  "response": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse",
    "result": {
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a new response object on the client side, after receiving the result from script.run and putting in only the key/value pairs that you need?

### Example client-side JS:

```js
let script_response = {
  "done": true,
  "response": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionResponse",
    "result": {
      "version": "v2",
      "content": {
        "messages": [{
          "text": "simple text with button",
          "type": "text"
        }]
      }
    }
  }
};
let my_kind_of_response = {
  "version": script_response.response.result.version,
  "content": script_response.response.result.content
}
console.log(my_kind_of_response);
/* Log: 
{
  "version": "v2",
  "content": {
    "messages": [
      {
        "text": "simple text with button",
        "type": "text"
      }
    ]
  }
}
*/
```

---

### References:

- [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply Aerials.

The thing is I already did that. What I showed up there was the response by Google. Here is my function:

function runWhenCalledByAPI(){

var success = {
  

  "version": "v2",
  "content": {
    "messages": [
      {
        "type": "text",
        "text": "simple text with button",
      }
    ],
    }
  };
  
 return success;
  
} 

It seems like that Google simply adds this part to the response (for whatever reason).

Any other take on how I can get rid of it?

Comment: You should create the new object on the client side after receiving the response from google.script.run. I updated my answer.